# Remove personal site URL from Search result

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, search-results

Is there a way to trim personal site URL's from Search result.

Mysite URL's are appearing in search result which we do not want.

Thanks,

Comment: Do you want to stop crawling People, or just remove the link to the personal site (which users can still get to but not from search)??

Comment: Hi Matthew, I just need to remove the link to the personal site. I managed to resolve this by Navigating to Query Rules of Search Center and then deactivating "People Name in SharePoint Search" rule provided by SharePoint. I am not sure if this is the best solution but it worked for me. If you have some better suggestions please guide.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to make for example a solution which prevents sites not to appear on search results from a certain web application. This does require some programming, but there might be similar solutions already available by just searching.

Another possibility could be to create a custom managed property - let's call it as *SitePath*. This managed property should be configured to not use `Complete Matching`. Now we could make a custom [Result Source](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj683115.aspx) to use *Query Transformation* such as `{searchTerms} (SitePath:/mySites)`. This assumes that your My Sites would be located under `mySites` URL. Now the result source could be added to be used on the SP Search.

Have a look at this blog post about [building a specialized search experience](http://blogs.technet.com/b/tothesharepoint/archive/2012/10/09/build-a-specialized-search-experience-in-minutes-with-sharepoint-2013.aspx).